# Ruby - count identical elements in array, add up, and print

Tags: ruby

I have this input .txt file loaded into array so it comes out like this:

```
class Note
  def initialize(a, b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end
end

input = File.open("DATA", "r")
input.each do |line|
  l = line.split(',')
  arr << Note.new(l[0], l[1])
end
```

I want to count and output to another .txt file how many times each inner array is equal to another inner array, e.g. `[500, 2, x]`, where `x` is the times the `[500, 2]` array is represented in `arr`.

input.txt example

```
10000, 150
00500, 10
08000, 171
00045, 92
00045, 93
00045, 92
00045, 93
```

expected output

```
10000, 150, 1
00500, 10, 1
08000, 171, 1
00045, 92, 2
00045, 93, 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At-least you could give us a ready made input array, so that we could concentrate on the needed code.. :)

Comment: the input .txt file can be with any numbers. with 2 numbers per line like 2453, 24

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
arr.uniq.map {|el| [*el, arr.count(el)] }
```

For each unique element of the array, count how may times it is there and make a new array with the element and its count.

Example:

```
arr = [[1,2], [5,5], [5,5], [8,7], [1,2], [5,5]]
#=> [[1, 2, 2], [5, 5, 3], [8, 7, 1]]
```

Comment: If in doubt, straight to the Ruby Documents. Nice

Comment: i get this output 10000  150
1
00500  10
1
08000  171
1
00045  92
1
00045  93
1
00045  92
1
00045  93
1

Comment: @user3052244 Nice. How I'm supposed to know if this output is correct or not? I would need the input.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal I have added input and output example

Comment: This is very slow at O(n²).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall indeed. Arup's solution is much faster. Thanks

Comment: This solution is more readable, though.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for :

```
arr = [[5000, 52],[99422, 1],[5000, 52],[325, 63]]
arr.group_by{|a| a }.map{|k,v| [*k,v.size]}
# => [[5000, 52, 2], [99422, 1, 1], [325, 63, 1]]
```

**Edit**

```
ar = File.readlines("/home/kirti/Ruby/input.txt").map{|s| s.scan(/\w+/) }
ar.group_by{|a| a }.map{|k,v| [*k,v.size]}
# => [["10000", "150", 1],
#     ["00500", "10", 1],
#     ["08000", "171", 1],
#     ["00045", "92", 2],
#     ["00045", "93", 2]]
```

Comment: i get this output 10000  150
1
00500  10
1
08000  171
1
00045  92
1
00045  93
1
00045  92
1
00045  93
1